# Behaviour of super in chained Scala traits

Tags: scala, traits

Why does `x.func` below return `"B extends B extends B"`?
How to arrange this code so that it returns `"B extends A extends Base"`?

```
trait Base {
  def name = "Base"
  def func = name
}

trait A extends Base {
  override def name = "A"
  override def func = name + " extends " + super.func
}

trait B extends Base {
  override def name = "B"
  override def func = name + " extends " + super.func
}

val x = new Base with A with B
println(x.func)
```

Update: One arrangement could be as follows. It now has identical definitions of `func1` in `A` and `B`. It does not work if I try to move it to the `Derived` class. Any ideas how to remove the repetition of `func1`?

```
trait Base {
  def name = "Base"
  def func1(s: String) = s
}

trait Derived extends Base {
  def func = func1(name)
}

trait A extends Derived {
  override def func1(s: String) = s + " extends " + super.func1(super.name)
  override def name = "A"
}

trait B extends Derived {
  override def func1(s: String) = s + " extends " + super.func1(super.name)
  override def name = "B"
}

val x = new Base with A with B
println(x.func)
```

Comment: A few more clarifications: In the real scenario name is an independent method that can not be inlined within func. Also, I am experimenting to see if definition of func could be somehow identical in all traits extending Base.

Answer (score 12):

I think the inheritance order may actually be the one your are seeking. If you replace the `" extends "` with one that shows which method of which trait is called:

```
trait Base {
  def name = "Base"
  def func = "Base." + name
}

trait A extends Base {
  override def name = "A"
  override def func = name + " A.extends " + super.func
}

trait B extends Base {
  override def name = "B"
  override def func = name + " B.extends " + super.func
}

val x = new Base with A with B
println(x.func)
// B B.extends B A.extends Base.B
```

It's just that `name` is always `"B"`. In other words:

```
trait Base { def func = "Base" } 
trait A extends Base { override def func = "A extends " + super.func }
trait B extends Base { override def func = "B extends " + super.func }
val x = new Base with A with B
println(x.func)
// B extends A extends Base
```

which is what you want...

The full linearization of your example is:

```
Object, B, A, Base, ScalaObject, AnyRef, Any
```

(see http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596155957/ScalaObjectSystem.html#Linearization for a practical explanation on how to figure out the linearization)

**Edit to answer comment:** why is the `name` always returns `"B"`? That's because the `def name` method is overridden by the trait `B` to return `"B"`. That's the whole point of inheritance, to be able to use in superclasses behavior that is refined in subclasses:

```
trait Legs { 
  def legs: Int 
  def printLegs() { println("I have " + legs + " legs") }
}

class Dog extends Legs { def legs = 4 }
class Chicken extends Legs { def legs = 2 }

new Dog printLegs
// I have 4 legs
new Chicken printLegs
// I have 2 legs
```

`legs` in trait `Legs` is not a separate one than `legs` in `Dog` depending on if you refer to it in `Legs` or `Dog`... Similarly, your `def name` will always return `"B"` if your object is a `B`.

It looks like you want to use name as a private method:

```
trait Base { 
  private def _name() = "Base"
  def func = _name
} 
trait A extends Base { 
  private def _name() = "A"
  override def func = _name + " extends " + super.func
}
trait B extends Base { 
  private def _name() = "B"
  override def func = _name + " extends " + super.func
}
val x = new Base with A with B
println(x.func)
// B extends A extends Base
```

I find that if there isn't a clear object model, using trait and inheritance quickly gets complicated. I assume you sanitized/simplified the example to use generic names like `A, B, Base, func` so that you get to the core of the issue, but on the other hand it doesn't give me any insights on what changes you could do to make it work for you. As you asked I've arrange the code so that it prints `"B extends A extends Base"`. I'm sure there are a bunch of other constraints that aren't in the question why it won't work for you.

Comment: "Its just that name is always B". Thats the crux of the question. Why is that? Thanks for the solution you proposed, but I do want the definition of func to be the same for each trait.

Comment: The trait's super calls are resolved at runtime. By saying `trait A extends B` you are stating that `A` can only be mixed into something that extends `B`. There is no way of knowing if `A` is mixed into a class which extends `B` directly or after few more stackable traits (`... with A with B`). So at the point of the trait's declaration it is impossible to determine which trait is going to be "above" this specific modification or in other words to which modification you super call will lead.

Comment: @huynhjl, please see the update to the question. Now trying to get rid of repetition of func1.

Comment: @MushtaqAhmed, I don't see that you took my other suggestions from my updated answer in your updated question. So I'm not sure whether I have any other good ideas as I don't have enough context and insight in the constraints you have.

Comment: @huynhjl I can not make name a private member in my design, hence could not make use of that approach. But you are right, maybe it is not possible to work on it without much context which I am struggling to abstract out.