# Clarification on how scala trait and subclass overriding combine

Tags: scala

Could someone confirm that I understand my testing below? It seems that when you add a trait in Scala to a class, that trait become the `super` for that class if you reference `super.symbol_defined_in_trait`. If the trait itself extends a base class, then the trait's `super` becomes the original implementation. Did I mess up or miss anything big?

```
class Base {
  def doStuff = println("Base did stuff")
}

trait WrapBase extends Base {
  override def doStuff = {
    println("WrapBase did stuff"); 
    super.doStuff
  }
}

class Sub1 extends Base

class Sub2 extends Base with WrapBase

class Sub3 extends Base {
  override def doStuff = {
    println("Sub3 did stuff"); 
    super.doStuff
  }
}

class Sub4 extends Base with WrapBase {
  override def doStuff = {
    println("Sub4 did stuff"); 
    super.doStuff
  }
}

class Sub5 extends Base with WrapBase {
  override def doStuff = {
    println("Sub5 did stuff"); 
  }
}
```

This testing prints out:

```
scala> (new Sub1).doStuff
Base did stuff

scala> (new Sub2).doStuff
WrapBase did stuff
Base did stuff

scala> (new Sub3).doStuff
Sub3 did stuff
Base did stuff

scala> (new Sub4).doStuff
Sub4 did stuff
WrapBase did stuff
Base did stuff

scala> (new Sub5).doStuff
Sub5 did stuff
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Behaviour of super in chained Scala traits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694600/behaviour-of-super-in-chained-scala-traits)

Comment: Perhaps, although that deals with multiple traits and this deals with the inheritance of mixing traits and classes. My scala is weak though - perhaps these are the same thing internally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inheritance in Scala comprise lattice - directed acyclic graph. The ultimate class that can be instantiated is constructed like a pie: The bottom is always some class, then there are a few traits. The order of traits is determined by the property - any trait doesn't depend on other traits that are above it. Or, equivalently, the trait can be mixed-in only on top of all it's dependencies.

**UPD:** The following idea is a **totally wrong**:

*The body of a class is also a "trait" and can be mixed not necessary on top, but also in the middle:*

```
object Sub6 extends Base with {
  override def doStuff = {
    println("Sub6 did stuff")
    super.doStuff
  }       
} with WrapBase
```

*And the result will be*

```
scala> Sub6.doStuff
WrapBase did stuff
Sub6 did stuff
Base did stuff
```

**Actually** I misunderstood the feature "Early Member Definitions" (http://www.scala-lang.org/old/sites/default/files/sids/nielsen/Tue,%202009-06-02,%2013:16/early-defs.pdf).

This syntax only work for initializing `val`s.

The example should have looked:

```
trait Sub6Changed extends Base {
  override def doStuff = {
    println("Sub6Changed did stuff") 
    super.doStuff
  }       
} 

object Sub6 extends Base with Sub6Changed with WrapBase
```

P.S. Thanks to [Cloud tech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2801947/cloud-tech)

Comment: That is really slick. Good to know

Comment: Can "{}" follow by "with", the code has compilation issue